# Get the value of a field if it exists in linq c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, many-to-many, exists

I've a Many to Many relation between a student (etudiant) and a course (cours) table which is called studentCours in SQL but not use as a model in Entity Framework (i've taken the habit of it now, even if i think its weird).

I need to show the result of the student (which is on another table etuResult) but the student may not have any result (nullable int) yet as the year is still in progress !

I'm able to get the value of studentCours and show them and also of studentResult, but i'm not able to show the concatenation of both (and leave the result empty or with other value than a number between 1 and 20).

On the following picture you can see :

On the left : the student with the id 3 has 2 cours with the id 1 and 10 (i dont know why the course_id 1 appears twice...) => These are the course he's following.

On the right : The student with the id 3 has one result for the course_id 10 and has the result 10/20

[image: getResult (left) and getCourse (right)]

Here are my two queries to get the data :

```
var etuCours = from c in bdd.cours
         where c.etudiant.Any(e => e.etudiant_id == id)
         select new resultCours { cours_id = c.cours_id, libelle = c.libelle, code = c.code, annee = c.annee };
IEnumerable<resultCours> etuResult = from er in bdd.etuResult
         where er.etudiant_id == id
         select new resultCours { cours_id = er.cours_id, cote = er.cote };
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Error? Unexpected results? Which results are expected?

Comment: The linq query is not correct :

The "cote" (result) for the cours_id 1 is not supposed to exist as the student has not result (means he subscribes to the cours which has the value cours_id 1 but haven't been tested yet).

So the left table DbQuery<resultCours> should have only one cours_id 1 without "cote" (cote field = null) and one course_id 10 with the "cote" (means result) of 10